# Spark : How to retrieve the original data for which stage has failed?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

When there is some exception while processing Spark attempts to re-process it three more times as we can see in below log. It then marks the Stage as failed. I want to retrieve all data for which the Stage has failed to analyse it later or do anything else with it. How can this be done? I am exploring this with SparkListeners but that seems to be developer API.

Thanks.

```
16/03/23 18:33:00 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 88, 192.168.213.53): java.lang.RuntimeException: Amit baby its exception time
    at com.yourcompany.custom.identifier.JavaRecoverableNetworkWordCount$1.call(JavaRecoverableNetworkWordCount.java:141)
    at com.yourcompany.custom.identifier.JavaRecoverableNetworkWordCount$1.call(JavaRecoverableNetworkWordCount.java:131)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:172)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

16/03/23 18:33:00 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.1 in stage 11.0 (TID 89, 192.168.213.53, NODE_LOCAL, 2535 bytes)
16/03/23 18:33:00 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.1 in stage 11.0 (TID 89) on executor 192.168.213.53: java.lang.RuntimeException (Amit baby its exception time) [duplicate 1]
16/03/23 18:33:00 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.2 in stage 11.0 (TID 90, 192.168.213.53, NODE_LOCAL, 2535 bytes)
16/03/23 18:33:00 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.2 in stage 11.0 (TID 90) on executor 192.168.213.53: java.lang.RuntimeException (Amit baby its exception time) [duplicate 2]
16/03/23 18:33:00 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.3 in stage 11.0 (TID 91, 192.168.213.53, NODE_LOCAL, 2535 bytes)
16/03/23 18:33:00 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.3 in stage 11.0 (TID 91) on executor 192.168.213.53: java.lang.RuntimeException (Amit baby its exception time) [duplicate 3]
16/03/23 18:33:00 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 1 in stage 11.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
16/03/23 18:33:00 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 11.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
16/03/23 18:33:00 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 11
```

Comment: Why is the question down voted?

Comment: You also got a close vote for being off-topic. That probably came together with the downvote. I don't see why someone would think this question is off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This cannot be done.** The data processed in a task does not typically live longer than the job it is part of. When the stage fails, the job exists no longer and the data is up for garbage collection. There is no reference to it, so you cannot get your hands on it.

*SparkListener* is indeed *DeveloperAPI*, but that does not mean you cannot use it. It's still a public API. It just means it's not guaranteed to be stable between Spark versions. We use *SparkListener* since maybe a year ago, and it's actually been perfectly stable. Feel free to give it a go. But I don't think it can solve your problem.

It's a valid and interesting idea though. Being able to access the data would help a great deal with debugging. You could put in a feature request in the [Spark JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK). It's not a simple thing to do though. The Spark task is way more complicated than just the user code you give it. So even if the task's input is made available for debugging, it's not trivial how you could make good use of it. Anyway it's worth a conversation I think!

Comment: Well checkpointing writes out the whole RDD. Yeah, if you checkpoint every RDD before a stage, you can pretty much reconstruct the task inputs. But this would be a huge overhead. You cannot go back and checkpoint the inputs upon failure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, one more thing, Is there any way I can update DAG after context is started? Sorry for throwing so many things at once.

Comment: Yes surely I can not go back, but cant SparkListener's onStageCompleted method be used to detect a failure.

Comment: When you create SparkContext the DAG is empty. Every RDD operation updates the DAG. I don't think I understand the question well. About `onStageCompleted`: Yes, you can detect a failure, but by then it's too late to create a checkpoint. So you need to create a checkpoint in advance, but doing this for every RDD operation will kill performance. (Maybe you have something in mind that can actually work. It may be best to just give it a try!)